# function call in R what does p in below code mean

Tags: r, function

I am new to R and trying to understand this function call below:

```
mle_mos <- function (n, m1, m2, x, x1, x2, initial, iters)  
    mvnewton (function (p) log_likelihood_gradient(p,n,m1,m2,x,x1,x2),   
            function (p) -fisher_information(p,n,m1,m2,x,x1,x2),   
            initial, iters)  


mvnewton <- function (f, g, x, n)  
{  
    print(f)
    if (n < 1)  
    stop("invalid number of iterations")  
  
    for (i in 1:n) {  
        cat("\nAt iteration",i,":\n\n")  
        cat("x =",x,"\n")  
        cat("f(x) =",f(x),"\n")  
        cat("g(x) =\n")  
        print(g(x));  
        x <- x - solve(g(x),f(x))  # computes inverse of g(x) times   
        f(x)  
    }  
    x  
}
```

mvnnewton takes
(function (p) log_likelihood_gradient(p,n,m1,m2,x,x1,x2)
as the first parameter.  Where is p getting it's value from? Where is it defined?  Can someone explain where p is getting a value to be passed into log_likelihood_gradient as a parameter?  I have been googling for the past 2 days and reading up a lot of stuff but am still not clear that I understand this properly.

Comment: Your code is not clear.  Please show a small reproducible example

Comment: `function (p) log_likelihood_gradient(p,n,m1,m2,x,x1,x2)` is a definition of a function.  It will get the value from the `mvnewton` function, for which it is an argument.

Comment: updated code, thanks user2554330, but I still don't understand

Answer (score 1):

## Arguments

If we have a function `fun`

```
fun <- function(z) z+1
```

and then we call it

```
fun(1)
```

1 is said to be the *actual argument* and `z` is said to be the *formal argument*.  The formal argument takes on the value of the actual argument so z takes on the value 1.  (There are some technicalities which we have glossed over but these do not affect the situation in the question.)

### mvnewton

When `mvnewton` is called the caller passes to it four actual arguments:

```
function (p) log_likelihood_gradient(p,n,m1,m2,x,x1,x2)

function (p) -fisher_information(p,n,m1,m2,x,x1,x2)

initial

iters
```

Note that the first two arguments are functions.  It does not pass the result of calling the functions but passes the functions themselves.

Now within `mvnewton` these 4 actual arguments correspond to the formal arguments `f`, `g`, `x` and `n` so when `mvnewton` refers to `f` it is really referring to

```
function (p) log_likelihood_gradient(p,n,m1,m2,x,x1,x2)
```

Also within `mvnewton` the function `f` is called with actual argument `x` and `x` corresponds to formal argument `p` within `f` (and similarly for `g`).

### Example

For example, suppose we call

```
f <- function(x) x^2
g <- function(x) 2*x
mvnewton(f, g, 1, 20)
```

Then `x` is 1 and the first time `f(x)` and `g(x)` are called within `mvnewton` they are called as `f(1)` and `g(1)` and within `f` and `g` the formal argument `p` takes the value 1.  `mvnewton` then updates `x` to a new value, calls `f` and `g` again with the new value of `x` and so on.

Comment: What is the difference between the p in function(p) and log_likelihood_gradient(p,n,m1,m2,x,x1,x2)

Comment: In `function (p) log_likelihood_gradient(p,n,m1,m2,x,x1,x2)` the first `p` is a formal argument and it is passed as an actual argument in the call to `log_likelihood_gradient` so `log_likelihood_gradient` winds up using whatever value was passed to `function (p) log_likelihood_gradient(p,n,m1,m2,x,x1,x2)` when the latter is called.